# Is it possible to use .htaccess|.htpasswd on Shiny Server?

Tags: r, .htaccess, shiny, shiny-server, .htpasswd

My workplace has a commercial shiny server. While the shinyapps deploy fine, I have attempted to inject .htaccess|.htpasswd without success. For example, I have created the necessary files and placed them in the directories:

*Directory where shinyapps are hosted*
/home/usrs/user1/shinyapps/myshinyapp1/myshinyapp1.R

*Where I have placed the `.htpasswd` file*
/home/usrs/user1/shinyapps/secretfiles/.htpasswd

*Where I have placed the `.htaccess` file*
/home/usrs/user1/shinyapps/myshinyapp1/.htaccess

Contents of `.htaccess` file

```
AuthName "This My Awesome Drupal Site Area!!.. Identify Yourself First."
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/usrs/user1/shinyapps/secretfiles/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

This works when testing at home, using XAMPP but when attempting to replicate at my worksite, it fails [nothing loads until I remove the `.htaccess` file].

Is it not possible to use this type of authentication for ShinyApps?

Answer (score 1):

Found out after reading more. In a nutshell, yes it can but has to be updated to allow .htaccess (httpd.conf `AllowOverride All`).